# Play 2.0 - closure compiler internal error in JavaScript asset

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, playframework-2.0

In my Play 2.0 project, I put the `processing-1.3.6.js` file, which is the javascript version of the Processing language into the `app/assets/scripts` folder and do nothing more. Now, when I try to access the website, Play tries to re-compile all the new stuff and stumbles upon the script. The error page in browser says this:

```
Compilation error
Internal Closure Compiler error (see logs)

In D:\programming\play-2.0\play-2.0\starlight\app\assets\scripts\processing-1.3.6.js at line 0.

0/*** 
1
2    P R O C E S S I N G . J S - 1.3.6
3    a port of the Processing visualization language
4
```

with the `0` line being the cause of the error. That is really strange because it is a comment. What to do? Maybe I am including the asset in my project incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play's closure compiler integration is broken on Windows, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/oCBbaeo4_4Y/UToOYcthnZQJ...

Comment: Oh my! I was expecting everything but not this. Another disappointment. Interesting, how the framework passed pre-release tests? Or is it never tested on Windows platform? Missing javascript support seems like a killer bug for a web framework, am I right?

Comment: Doesn't look like any of their developers use Windows, see https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/274-closure-compiler-broken-in-windows. Note that you can just copy the script into the /public directory and have it served unprocessed.

Comment: If I do so, what will be my routing like then? I mean, how to make a route to a js file in the public folder?

Comment: Your 'routes' file should already have an entry like 'GET  /public/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)' to access static assets directly.